# How can I call this webservice asynchronously?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

In Visual Studio I created a **web service** (and checked "generate asynchronous operations") on this URL:

> http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx

and can get the data out **synchronously** but what is the syntax for getting the data out **asychronously**?

```
using System.Windows;
using TestConsume2343.ServiceReference1;
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace TestConsume2343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new GlobalWeatherSoapClient();

            //synchronous
            string getWeatherResult = client.GetWeather("Berlin", "Germany");
            Console.WriteLine("Get Weather Result: " + getWeatherResult); //works

            //asynchronous
            client.BeginGetWeather("Berlin", "Germany", new AsyncCallback(GotWeather), null);
        }

        void GotWeather(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Get Weather Result: " + result.???); 
        }

    }
}
```

## Answer:

Thanks TLiebe, with your **EndGetWeather** suggestion I was able to get it to work like this:

```
using System.Windows;
using TestConsume2343.ServiceReference1;
using System;

namespace TestConsume2343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new GlobalWeatherSoapClient();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client.BeginGetWeather("Berlin", "Germany", new AsyncCallback(GotWeather), null);
        }

        void GotWeather(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get Weather Result: " + client.EndGetWeather(result).ToString()); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Did nothing print? Well it wont if the code is commented out.

Comment: well if I just output "result", it prints: Get Weather Result: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel+SendAsyncResult, I don't know where the data is in the "result" object, I want to access the data as I do with "e.Result" in this example: http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GotWeather() method you need to call the EndGetWeather() method.  Have a look at some of the sample code at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480516.aspx).  You need to use the IAsyncResult object to get your delegate method so that you can call the EndGetWeather() method.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest using the event provided by the auto-generated proxy instead of messing with the AsyncCallback

```
public void DoWork()
{
    GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new GlobalWeatherSoapClient();
    client.GetWeatherCompleted += new EventHandler<WeatherCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetWeatherCompleted);
    client.GetWeatherAsync("Berlin", "Germany");
}

void client_GetWeatherCompleted(object sender, WeatherCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get Weather Result: " + e.Result);
}
```